# Woocommerce redirect checkout-form after validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and after purchase validation through form-checkout.php, I can't forward some variables (eg: price, order num, etc...) to another URL through the form by using POST method.

I replace this line:

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

by this line:

```
 <form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="https://www.smt-sps.com.tn/paiement/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But doesn't work… I hope that someone can help.

Comment: Please improve the description of your issue by adding more information. For example, what is contained in $_POST? How do you know exactly, that it doesn't work - describe the error precisely.